# How to invoke a c# function to fill value into razor html textbox?

Tags: c#, powershell, razor, model-view-controller

I am using the function that fetches the output from PowerShell script into the output String variable. I need to call that function inside an @HTMLTextBox to load the value.

I have created the function and using razor format to invoke the function inside the textbox element.

```
@using System.Management.Automation
@functions {

public string PowerShellExecutor(string script) {
    var shell = PowerShell.Create();
    string outString = "";
    shell.Commands.AddScript(script);
    var results = shell.Invoke();
    if (results.Count>0)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var psObj in results)
        {
            builder.Append(psObj.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");

        }
        outString = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
    }
    return outString;
  }
}

<div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.TextBox("txtDirectory", @PowerShellExecutor("$env:USERDNSDOMAIN") , new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number"})
</div>
```

The textbox is suppose to fill the value of the output obtained when the command is passed through the function. However, It shows blank.

Comment: remove this part `@type = "number"`

Comment: Oops my bad ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the @ for the `PowerShellExecutor` and you should also remove  `@type = "number"` to make your text box accept a string.

```
@Html.TextBox("txtDirectory", PowerShellExecutor("$env:USERDNSDOMAIN") , new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, was just about to clarify on that thanks to @Elyas Esna